# How to fetch exact parameter from XML string with PHP?

Tags: php, xml

This is part of XML document:

```
<entry>
<author>
      <name>Dunnock_D</name>
      <uri>http://www.flickr.com/people/dunnock_d/</uri>
 </author>
    <link rel="license" type="text/html" href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc/2.0/deed.en" />
    <link rel="enclosure" type="image/jpeg" href="http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7548/26820724620_1d221c3187_b.jpg" />
</entry>
```

My code:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($result);

    foreach ($xml->entry as $pixinfo) {

       echo $pixinfo->link[1]['href'];

    }
```

The problem is there can be one or more link strings and I need only particular with **rel="enclosure"** attribute.
What is the easiest way without extra IF and loops?

Thank you!

Comment: I think you could apply templates for this and select all link items where the rel attribute is enclosure.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you parse and process HTML/XML in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

For that you can use [DOMXPath](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php), more specifically the [query](http://php.net/manual/en/domxpath.query.php) function. Let's say your `$result` variable contains the following:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<entries>
    <entry>
        <author>
              <name>Dunnock_D</name>
              <uri>http://www.flickr.com/people/dunnock_d/</uri>
         </author>
        <link rel="license" type="text/html" href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc/2.0/deed.en" />
        <link rel="enclosure" type="image/jpeg" href="http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7548/26820724620_1d221c3187_b.jpg" />
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <author>
              <name>Dunnock_D</name>
              <uri>http://www.flickr.com/people/dunnock_d/</uri>
         </author>
        <link rel="license" type="text/html" href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc/2.0/deed.en" />
        <link rel="enclosure" type="image/jpeg" href="http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7548/26820724620_1d221c3187_b.jpg" />
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <author>
              <name>Dunnock_D</name>
              <uri>http://www.flickr.com/people/dunnock_d/</uri>
         </author>
        <link rel="license" type="text/html" href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc/2.0/deed.en" />
        <link rel="enclosure" type="image/jpeg" href="http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7548/26820724620_1d221c3187_b.jpg" />
    </entry>
</entries>
```

I know the entries are repeated, but it's only for demo purposes. The code to get only the enclosure links would be:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$doc->loadXML($result);

$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
$entries = $xpath->query('//entries/entry');

foreach ($entries as $entry) {
    $link = $xpath->query('link[@rel="enclosure"]', $entry)->item(0);

    $href = $link->getAttribute('href');

    echo "{$href}\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using simplexml. Just use "attributes()" function: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/simplexmlelement.attributes.php

Or you can access directly:

```
foreach ($xml->entry as $pixinfo) {
    if($pixinfo->link[1]['rel'] == 'enclosure') {
        echo $pixinfo->link[1]['href'];
    }
}
```

Comment: In this loop we will not take necessary data if for example there only one link string:                                                                                                              `<entry>
        <author>
              <name>Dunnock_D</name>
              <uri>http://www.flickr.com/people/dunnock_d/</uri>
         </author>
        <link rel="enclosure" type="image/jpeg" href="http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7548/26820724620_1d221c3187_b.jpg" />
    </entry>`

Comment: You right. If you know exactly your XML, just remove the foreach loop and be happy :)

Answer (score 0):

The solution is Xpath.

With SimpleXML you can fetch the attribute node and cast the generated SimpleXMLElement into a string. You should make sure that you got an element before you cast it. `SimpleXMLElement::xpath()` will always return an array of `SimpleXMLElement` objects.

```
$entry = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
$enclosures = $entry->xpath('link[@rel="enclosure"]/@href');

if (count($enclosures) > 0) {
  var_dump((string)$enclosures[0]);
}
```

Output:

```
string(63) "http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7548/26820724620_1d221c3187_b.jpg"
```

With DOM the bootstrap is slightly larger, but you can fetch the href attribute directly as a string:

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXml($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);

var_dump(
  $xpath->evaluate('string(/entry/link[@rel="enclosure"]/@href)')
);
```

This will return an empty string if the expression does not match.

Comment: Thanks @ThW! that's I was looking for!